# How to find out employee which are joined leap year with SQL

Tags: sql

The organization need 50 years data which are joined in leap year.So, which way I find out this SQL query?

Comment: It is based on the data present in the table. If you manage to post the columns present in table and what you have tried, people here could be able to help you.

Comment: With the information given, how do you think people can help you???

Comment: Here's a guide to learn how to ask a question.  https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask